# Validation 2 fields with yup and formik

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

This is my default value:

```
const defaultValues = {
    busi_day: [],
    busi_start_time: '09:00',
    busi_end_time: '17:00',
  };
```

This is my 2 fields:

```
<FastField type="time" className="start-time" name="busi_start_time" value={values.busi_start_time} />
<FastField type="time" className="start-time" name="busi_end_time" value={values.busi_end_time} />
```

This is my validatio using Yup:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    busi_start_time: Yup.string()
      .required(),
    busi_end_time: Yup.string()
      .required(),
  });
```

Now, I want to validate that the busi_end_time must be after the busi_start_time. For example:
{busi_start_time: '09:00'  busi_end_time: '17:00'} is valid but {busi_start_time: '14:00'  busi_end_time: '08:00'} is not valid. How I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library and code below:

```
  Yup.object().shape({
  busi_start_time: Yup.string().required("Start time cannot be empty"),
  busi_end_time: Yup.string()
    .required("end time cannot be empty")
    .test("is-greater", "End time should be greater", function (value) {
      const { busi_start_time} = this.parent;
      return moment(value, "HH:mm").isSameOrAfter(moment(busi_start_time, "HH:mm"));
    })
});
```

Comment: I use console.log to log start but it is undefined. I use functional syntax

Comment: @LXT strange. I created simple sandbox here : https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-swartz-yr9m6t?file=/src/index.js . Can you verify this is working?

Comment: @LXT I relaized that I made a typo. I updated my answer. It should be fine now

Comment: I change this.parent to `this.parent.busi_start_time` and it can take the value of busi_start_time but when I enter the endtime after the start time, it still shoot an error "end time should be greater"

Comment: @LXT as far as I can see in code sandbox that I provided everything works as expected. Can you verify this?

Comment: Ok I also see your error typo. I tried it and succeed. Thank you so much